# Compille with 3rd party librarys not work

Tags: c++, windows, compiler-errors

I need to use a Genetic Algorithm library called GALib for a computer science project and the code must run in Windows. I download the library and try to compile the main.cpp.
I cheked the files are in the locations.
The headers and dev files are in ..\lib\galib\galib247-c2014\ and the static library in ..\lib\galib\galib.a

I tried this:
`g++ -I ..\lib\galib\galib247-c2014\ ..\lib\galib\galib.a .\AG--n-reinas.cpp -o reinas.exe`
And I get this error:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\pacop\AppData\Local\Temp\cc19sAiM.o:AG--n-reinas.cpp:(.text+0x25e): undefined reference to `GASimpleGA::GASimpleGA(GAGenome const&)'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\pacop\AppData\Local\Temp\cc19sAiM.o:AG--n-reinas.cpp:(.text+0x275): undefined reference to `GASimpleGA::minimaxi(int)'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\pacop\AppData\Local\Temp\cc19sAiM.o:AG--n-reinas.cpp:(.text+0x28b): undefined reference to `GASimpleGA::populationSize(unsigned int)'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\pacop\AppData\Local\Temp\cc19sAiM.o:AG--n-reinas.cpp:(.text+0x372): undefined reference to `GAStatistics::bestIndividual(unsigned int) const'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\pacop\AppData\Local\Temp\cc19sAiM.o:AG--n-reinas.cpp:(.text+0x460): undefined reference to `GASimpleGA::~GASimpleGA()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\pacop\AppData\Local\Temp\cc19sAiM.o:AG--n-reinas.cpp:(.text+0x49e): undefined reference to `GASimpleGA::~GASimpleGA()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\pacop\AppData\Local\Temp\cc19sAiM.o:AG--n-reinas.cpp:(.text$_ZN15GAParameterList3setEPKcj[__ZN15GAParameterList3setEPKcj]+0x1c): undefined reference to `GAParameterList::set(char const*, void const*)'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\pacop\AppData\Local\Temp\cc19sAiM.o:AG--n-reinas.cpp:(.text$_ZN23GARouletteWheelSelectorC2Ei[__ZN23GARouletteWheelSelectorC2Ei]+0x1d): undefined reference to `vtable for GARouletteWheelSelector'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\pacop\AppData\Local\Temp\cc19sAiM.o:AG--n-reinas.cpp:(.text$_ZN23GARouletteWheelSelectorD2Ev[__ZN23GARouletteWheelSelectorD2Ev]+0xa): undefined reference to `vtable for GARouletteWheelSelector'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\pacop\AppData\Local\Temp\cc19sAiM.o:AG--n-reinas.cpp:(.text$_ZN20GATournamentSelectorC1Ei[__ZN20GATournamentSelectorC1Ei]+0x1d): undefined reference to `vtable for GATournamentSelector'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\pacop\AppData\Local\Temp\cc19sAiM.o:AG--n-reinas.cpp:(.text$_ZN20GATournamentSelectorD1Ev[__ZN20GATournamentSelectorD1Ev]+0xa): undefined reference to `vtable for GATournamentSelector'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\pacop\AppData\Local\Temp\cc19sAiM.o:AG--n-reinas.cpp:(.text$_ZN18GAGeneticAlgorithm6evolveEj[__ZN18GAGeneticAlgorithm6evolveEj]+0x68): undefined reference to `GAStatistics::flushScores()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\pacop\AppData\Local\Temp\cc19sAiM.o:AG--n-reinas.cpp:(.text$_ZN18GAGeneticAlgorithm10pCrossoverEf[__ZN18GAGeneticAlgorithm10pCrossoverEf]+0x22): undefined reference to `GAParameterList::set(char const*, double)'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\pacop\AppData\Local\Temp\cc19sAiM.o:AG--n-reinas.cpp:(.text$_ZN18GAGeneticAlgorithm9pMutationEf[__ZN18GAGeneticAlgorithm9pMutationEf]+0x22): undefined reference to `GAParameterList::set(char const*, double)'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\pacop\AppData\Local\Temp\cc19sAiM.o:AG--n-reinas.cpp:(.text$_ZN18GAGeneticAlgorithm8selectorERK17GASelectionScheme[__ZN18GAGeneticAlgorithm8selectorERK17GASelectionScheme]+0x1b): undefined reference to `GAPopulation::selector(GASelectionScheme const&)'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\pacop\AppData\Local\Temp\cc19sAiM.o:AG--n-reinas.cpp:(.text$_ZN10GASimpleGA8selectorERK17GASelectionScheme[__ZN10GASimpleGA8selectorERK17GASelectionScheme]+0x1b): undefined reference to `GAPopulation::selector(GASelectionScheme const&)'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\pacop\AppData\Local\Temp\cc19sAiM.o:AG--n-reinas.cpp:(.text$_Z11GARandomIntii[__Z11GARandomIntii]+0x16): undefined reference to `garan2()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\pacop\AppData\Local\Temp\cc19sAiM.o:AG--n-reinas.cpp:(.text$_Z13GARandomFloatv[__Z13GARandomFloatv]+0x7): undefined reference to `garan2()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\pacop\AppData\Local\Temp\cc19sAiM.o:AG--n-reinas.cpp:(.text$_ZN15GA1DArrayGenomeIiE17OnePointCrossoverERK8GAGenomeS3_PS1_S4_[__ZN15GA1DArrayGenomeIiE17OnePointCrossoverERK8GAGenomeS3_PS1_S4_]+0x1cf): undefined reference to `GAErr(GASourceLocator, char const*, char const*, GAErrorIndex, char const*, char const*)'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\pacop\AppData\Local\Temp\cc19sAiM.o:AG--n-reinas.cpp:(.text$_ZN15GA1DArrayGenomeIiE17OnePointCrossoverERK8GAGenomeS3_PS1_S4_[__ZN15GA1DArrayGenomeIiE17OnePointCrossoverERK8GAGenomeS3_PS1_S4_]+0x2a8): undefined reference to `GAErr(GASourceLocator, char const*, char const*, GAErrorIndex, char const*, char const*)'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\pacop\AppData\Local\Temp\cc19sAiM.o:AG--n-reinas.cpp:(.text$_ZN15GA1DArrayGenomeIiE17OnePointCrossoverERK8GAGenomeS3_PS1_S4_[__ZN15GA1DArrayGenomeIiE17OnePointCrossoverERK8GAGenomeS3_PS1_S4_]+0x52e): undefined reference to `GAErr(GASourceLocator, char const*, char const*, GAErrorIndex, char const*, char const*)'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\pacop\AppData\Local\Temp\cc19sAiM.o:AG--n-reinas.cpp:(.text$_ZN15GA1DArrayGenomeIiE17OnePointCrossoverERK8GAGenomeS3_PS1_S4_[__ZN15GA1DArrayGenomeIiE17OnePointCrossoverERK8GAGenomeS3_PS1_S4_]+0x5f1): undefined reference to `GARandomBit()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\pacop\AppData\Local\Temp\cc19sAiM.o:AG--n-reinas.cpp:(.text$_ZN15GAAlleleSetCoreIiED1Ev[__ZN15GAAlleleSetCoreIiED1Ev]+0x6f): undefined reference to `GAErr(GASourceLocator, char const*, char const*, GAErrorIndex, char const*, char const*)'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\pacop\AppData\Local\Temp\cc19sAiM.o:AG--n-reinas.cpp:(.text$_ZN15GA1DArrayGenomeIiEC2EjPFfR8GAGenomeEPv[__ZN15GA1DArrayGenomeIiEC2EjPFfR8GAGenomeEPv]+0x36): undefined reference to `GAGenome::NoInitializer(GAGenome&)'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\pacop\AppData\Local\Temp\cc19sAiM.o:AG--n-reinas.cpp:(.text$_ZN15GA1DArrayGenomeIiEC2EjPFfR8GAGenomeEPv[__ZN15GA1DArrayGenomeIiEC2EjPFfR8GAGenomeEPv]+0x3d): undefined reference to `GAGenome::GAGenome(void (*)(GAGenome&), int (*)(GAGenome&, float), float (*)(GAGenome const&, GAGenome const&))'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\pacop\AppData\Local\Temp\cc19sAiM.o:AG--n-reinas.cpp:(.text$_ZN15GA1DArrayGenomeIiEC1EjPFfR8GAGenomeEPv[__ZN15GA1DArrayGenomeIiEC1EjPFfR8GAGenomeEPv]+0x36): undefined reference to `GAGenome::NoInitializer(GAGenome&)'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\pacop\AppData\Local\Temp\cc19sAiM.o:AG--n-reinas.cpp:(.text$_ZN15GA1DArrayGenomeIiEC1EjPFfR8GAGenomeEPv[__ZN15GA1DArrayGenomeIiEC1EjPFfR8GAGenomeEPv]+0x3d): undefined reference to `GAGenome::GAGenome(void (*)(GAGenome&), int (*)(GAGenome&, float), float (*)(GAGenome const&, GAGenome const&))'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\pacop\AppData\Local\Temp\cc19sAiM.o:AG--n-reinas.cpp:(.text$_ZN15GA1DArrayGenomeIiED2Ev[__ZN15GA1DArrayGenomeIiED2Ev]+0x27): undefined reference to `GAGenome::~GAGenome()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\pacop\AppData\Local\Temp\cc19sAiM.o:AG--n-reinas.cpp:(.text$_ZN15GA1DArrayGenomeIiED1Ev[__ZN15GA1DArrayGenomeIiED1Ev]+0x27): undefined reference to `GAGenome::~GAGenome()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\pacop\AppData\Local\Temp\cc19sAiM.o:AG--n-reinas.cpp:(.text$_ZNK11GAAlleleSetIiE6alleleEv[__ZNK11GAAlleleSetIiE6alleleEv]+0xa9): undefined reference to `GAErr(GASourceLocator, char const*, char const*, GAErrorIndex, char const*, char const*)'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\pacop\AppData\Local\Temp\cc19sAiM.o:AG--n-reinas.cpp:(.text$_ZNK11GAAlleleSetIiE6alleleEv[__ZNK11GAAlleleSetIiE6alleleEv]+0x10c): undefined reference to `GAErr(GASourceLocator, char const*, char const*, GAErrorIndex, char const*, char const*)'        
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\pacop\AppData\Local\Temp\cc19sAiM.o:AG--n-reinas.cpp:(.text$_ZNK15GA1DArrayGenomeIiE5cloneEN8GAGenome11CloneMethodE[__ZNK15GA1DArrayGenomeIiE5cloneEN8GAGenome11CloneMethodE]+0x76): undefined reference to `GAGenome::copy(GAGenome const&)'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\pacop\AppData\Local\Temp\cc19sAiM.o:AG--n-reinas.cpp:(.text$_ZN15GA1DArrayGenomeIiE4copyERK8GAGenome[__ZN15GA1DArrayGenomeIiE4copyERK8GAGenome]+0x63): undefined reference to `GAGenome::copy(GAGenome const&)'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\pacop\AppData\Local\Temp\cc19sAiM.o:AG--n-reinas.cpp:(.text$_ZN15GA1DArrayGenomeIiE4readERSi[__ZN15GA1DArrayGenomeIiE4readERSi]+0x6b): undefined reference to `GAErr(GASourceLocator, char const*, char const*, GAErrorIndex, char const*, char const*)'   
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

`g++ -I ..\lib\galib\galib247-c2014\ ..\lib\galib\galib.a .\AG--n-reinas.cpp -o reinas.exe`

I got the same error

And last I tried:
`g++ -o reinas.out .\AG--n-reinas.cpp -I ..\lib\galib\galib247-c2014\ -L ..\lib\galib\galib247-c2014\ -l..\lib\galib\galib.a` and `g++ -o reinas.out .\AG--n-reinas.cpp -I ..\lib\galib\galib247-c2014\ -l..\lib\galib\galib.a`

And the error changed to:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -l..\lib\galib\galib.a
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can someone explain me how to compile it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe this will be useful http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Specify_the_libraries_for_the_linker_to_use

Comment: .a files go after the .cpp files that need them on the commandline

Comment: Also consider investing in a build system like CMake or Make